# Container type class in Haskell

Tags: haskell, containers

I have an idea to create a `Container` class to use **any** container-like type universally:

```
class Container c where
    at :: (Eq k) => c a -> k -> a
```

But at attempt to use an instance of this class as (for example) a `List` will be disappointing:

```
{- not working code -}
instance Container [a] where
    at lst k = lst !! k
```

The `List` demands `Int` but we have only `Eq`:

> ```
> • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘k’
>   ‘k’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>     the type signature for:
>       at :: forall k v. Eq k => [a] -> k -> v
> ```

We can not do like this:

```
class Container c where
    at :: c a -> Int -> v
```

because the whole point is lost, since we'd like to use as a 'key' of the container not only `Int`, but also any other `Eq` type such as `String`, `(Int, Int)`, `Bool` etc.

An example to do it in a wrong way (I did it but I didn't like it):

```
class Container c where
    at :: (Show k, Eq k) => c a -> k -> a


toInt :: (Show s) => s -> Int
toInt r = let s = show r
          in  (read s :: Int)


instance Container [] where
    at arr k = arr !! toInt k

{-
*R.Container> at [1,2,3] 1
2
-}

toBool :: (Show s) => s -> Bool
toBool r = let s = show r
           in  (read s :: Bool)


data MyPair a = MyPair { ifTrue :: a, ifFalse :: a } deriving (Show)


instance Container MyPair where
    at (MyPair a b) k = let yes = toBool k
                        in  if yes then a else b 

{-
*R.Container> let myPair = MyPair 12 13
*R.Container> at myPair True
12
*R.Container> at myPair False
13
-}

toIntPair :: (Show s) => s -> (Int,Int)
toIntPair r = let s = show r
           in  (read s :: (Int,Int))

data Matrix a = Matrix {arr2d :: [[a]]} deriving (Show)


instance Container Matrix where
    at mtrx k = let (f,s) = toIntPair k
                    arrs = arr2d mtrx
                    arr = arrs !! f
                in  arr !! s

{-
*R.Container> let mtrx = Matrix [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,12,11,10]] 
*R.Container> at mtrx (3,1)
12
*R.Container> at mtrx (3,0)
13
-}
```

So I have to use `Show` constraint for every conversation function which contains slow conversions from `Eq` to the required type

My question is how to implement this idea in the best way (good practice) and without language extensions (`{-# LANGUAGE`)?

Comment: Your signature `at :: (Eq k) => c -> k -> v` means that for any type `k`, I can retrieve a value of any type `v` for that container, so even if your container stores `Int`s, I can decide to retrieve `String`s from it?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I corrected that to `c a -> k -> a`

Comment: Since `c` is a type *constructor*, you would need to define the instance for `[]`, not `[a]`.

Comment: You can have a look at the `Relude.Extra.Map` module for an idea on how to implement similar typeclass: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/relude-0.5.0/docs/Relude-Extra-Map.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Control.Lens.At](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-At.html), and perhaps ask a more specific question after you've seen what's done there? Admittedly that's done with the slightly different goal of setting up lenses, but it amounts to much the same thing. I'll try to give a brief explanation of how it works though.

First, it's worth noting that what you want would be better seen as an associative mapping typeclass rather than a container, as you wish to be able to look up the value at a `k`.

Thus, Control.Lens.At sets up two type families, `Index` and `IxValue`, for the key and value type of the container. For example, a `Map k v` [has](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/src/Control.Lens.At.html#line-287) `Index (Map k v) = k` and `IxValue (Map k v) = v` as you might expect (eliding that `k` must be `Ord`), whereas a list can be thought of as a mapping from indices to its values, [thus](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/src/Control.Lens.At.html#line-94) `Index [a] = Int`, `IxValue [a] = a`.

These type families are used to construct the typeclass `Ixed` saying, given a container `:: c` and an `k = Index c` then I can retrieve an `v :: Maybe (IxValue c)` (depending on whether it's present or not) (and indeed modify at `k` instead if desired). As I said earlier, this is done to set up lenses, but this approach could be adapted if desired.

---

You could also take a look at [IsMap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.11.0/docs/Data-Containers.html) for another point in the design space. No language extensions used there either.

Comment: It would be a good idea to incorporate some of the code blocks into the answer. It is considered good practice on SO to not have answers that are heavily dependent on external resources (citations are, of course, good to have though).